# Outline of changes to the iOS Developer Program License Agreement

Tags: ios, developer-program, license

From time to time Apple updates their iOS Developer Program License Agreement, but, unfortunately, they never provide any clues as to what they changed since the previous version of the agreement. This means that after each change I need to read through the *entire* agreement and hope that I catch any of the new stuff they introduced.

Do you know of any place where a summary of the changes between versions of the agreement is presented (possibly somewhere on one of Apple's sites and I just missed it)?

An alternative might be an application that provides a visual difference between two PDF documents. I tried out [DiffPDF](http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html), but it turned out that this app is not sophisticated enough to handle the accumulating changes after a few pages. If you have a different suggestion it would be welcome.

Comment: anyone got the 2017/02/27 version and the previous one for comparison?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a very nice site that publicly calls out changes to Apple's developer terms.

- http://www.appstorereviewguidelineshistory.com

Before them, I've not seen anyone that provides these publicly, so I've resorted to saving the PDF to a folder every time I'm prompted that there is a change. I just append the YYYYmmDD of the agreement to the file name so I can see where exactly the agreement with Apple is changing.

From there, a tool like [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com) can run a graphical `diff` on the text if you copy it into a TextEdit document or otherwise get the content out of it's PDF container. Preview will allow you to copy all the text and paste it into a Text Edit document, but I also have a Folder Action created in Automator to convert any PDF file dropped into it's folder into a rich text file and dump the result on my Desktop.

Comment: Hm, it never occurred to me to do a pure textual diff on the content of the PDF. I just tried it, and I must admit that the result is not too bad - way better than what I get from DiffPDF in any case. I'm working with [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) instead of Kaleidoscope, and it's quite slow, but hey - you can't have everything :-)

Comment: Converting them to text also helps greatly. Select all in preview and paste into TextEdit is worth it.

Answer (score 5):

The http://www.appstorereviewguidelineshistory.com is for review guidelines, 
not for the iOS Developer Program License Agreement

Try this: https://www.diffchecker.com/8cxz8j14

Comment: That diffchecker link is nice. Someone should do this every time and collect those.

Answer (score 0):

Export the PDFs to MS Word, then use Review/Compare to see the differences.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you mentioned how to get the old PDF when the new agreement is launched